# spark scala sameElement doesn't work as expected

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataFrame of date  :

```
val df = Seq(Date.valueOf("2020-01-01"), Date.valueOf("2020-11-11"), Date.valueOf("1992-04-10")).toDF("dt")
df.show
+----------+
|        dt|
+----------+
|2020-01-01|
|2020-11-11|
|1992-04-10|
+----------+
```

using spark I add two months to that dateFrame :
df.select(add_months(df("dt"))

```
 df.select(add_months(df("dt"), 2)).show 
+-----------------+
|add_months(dt, 2)|
+-----------------+
|       2020-03-01|
|       2021-01-11|
|       1992-06-10|
+-----------------+
```

then I collected the result and try to see if its equals to an expected value (which, normaly does) ;

```
val expected = Array(Row("2020-03-01"), Row("2021-01-11"), Row("1992-06-10")
val actue = df.select(add_months(df("dt"), 2)).collect()
actue.sameElements(expected)
```

how ever it returns **false**
I also tried  just one values it returns always **false**

```
scala> actue.sameElements(expected)
false
```

can anyone spot what is the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Method `sameElements`

`def sameElements[B >: String](that: scala.collection.GenIterable[B]): Boolean`

`[B >: String]` means this Type Parameter B must be either same as String or Super-Type of String

`expected` & `actue` are of type Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row], org.apache.spark.sql.Row is not same as String or not super type of String.

Convert `org.apache.spark.sql.Row` to `String` and check if both are same or not. Check below code.

```
scala> val expected = Array("2020-03-01", "2021-01-11", "1992-06-10")
expected: Array[String] = Array(2020-03-01, 2021-01-11, 1992-06-10)
```

```
scala> val actue = df.select(add_months(df("dt"), 2).as("dt")).as[String].collect
actue: Array[String] = Array(2020-03-01, 2021-01-11, 1992-06-10)
```

```
scala> actue.sameElements(expected)
res8: Boolean = true
```